# How to sort a date that stored in array of struct inside a struct?

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, struct

im making program in C, one of the feature i need to build is sort a date from many user and many order, this is how my struct and current code look like, index are how much user registered

```
struct Order {
    int weight;
    int status;
    char date[8];

}
order;

struct User {
    char login[25];
    char password[25];
    int price;
    struct Order order[25];
    int manyOrder;
}
user;

for (i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
    for (int f = 0; f < user[i].manyOrder; f++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= index - i - 1; j++) {
        if (strcmp(user[i].order[f].date, user[i].order[f + 1].date) > 0) {
        temp[0].order[0] = user[i].order[f];
        user[i].order[f] = user[i].order[f + 1];
        user[i].order[f + 1] = temp[0].order[0];

        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a `main`, and/or the function that should include the loops you posted.

Comment: its rly long program, i think its too long to post here

Comment: Do you mean that for each user, you want to sort `order[25]` by date ? Then I suggest to make a separate function to sort an array of order. And also have a look at the way the date is stored if you use `strcmp` : YYYYMMDD may be a good choice.

Comment: @aryads See updated answer. There was a bug in the first posted answer. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

In C whenever you hear the two words "sort" and "array" in the same sentence, you first thought should be: `qsort`

`qsort` will sort any array for you. All you need is to write a compare function.

Something like:

```
int compare_func (const void * a, const void * b){
    const struct Order* pA = a;
    const struct Order* pB = b;
    return strcmp(pA->date, pB->Date);
}
```

and then call it like:

```
qsort(user[i].order, user[i].manyOrder, sizeof user[i].order[0], compare_func);
```

BTW: I guess you want the date in the form YYYYMMDD which is 8 characters. So to store it as a string, you'll need an array with 9 element, i.e. one extra for the string termination. In other words: `char date[8];` --> `char date[9];`

Putting it together:

```
struct Order
{
    int weight;
    int status;
    char date[9];  // Notice 9 instead of 8  
};                 // Notice: Don't put "order" here. It will give a global variable 

struct User
{
    char login[25];
    char password[25];
    int price;
    struct Order order[25];
    int manyOrder;
};                 // Notice: Don't put "user" here. It will give a global variable

int compare_func (const void * a, const void * b){
    const struct Order* pA = a;
    const struct Order* pB = b;
    return strcmp(pA->date, pB->date);
}

void print_user(const struct User* p)
{
    puts(p->login);
    puts(p->password);
    printf("%d\n", p->price);
    puts("------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < p->manyOrder; ++i)
    {
        printf("   %d\n", p->order[i].weight);
        printf("   %d\n", p->order[i].status);
        printf("   %s\n", p->order[i].date);
    }
    puts("------------");
    printf("%d\n", p->manyOrder);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct User user[] = {
        {"lg1", "pw1", 42, {{1, 2, "20200601"},{3, 4, "20200501"},{5, 6, "20200401"}}, 3},
        {"lg2", "pw2", 43, {{10, 20, "20200601"},{30, 40, "20200501"},{50, 60, "20200401"},{70, 80, "20200801"},{90, 100, "20200501"}}, 5}
    };

    puts("BEFORE SORTING:");    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof user/sizeof user[0]); ++i)
    {
        print_user(user+i);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof user/sizeof user[0]); ++i)
    {
        qsort(user[i].order, user[i].manyOrder, sizeof user[i].order[0], compare_func);
    }

    puts("");    
    puts("AFTER SORTING:");    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof user/sizeof user[0]); ++i)
    {
        print_user(user+i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
BEFORE SORTING:
lg1
pw1
42
------------
   1
   2
   20200601
   3
   4
   20200501
   5
   6
   20200401
------------
3
lg2
pw2
43
------------
   10
   20
   20200601
   30
   40
   20200501
   50
   60
   20200401
   70
   80
   20200801
   90
   100
   20200501
------------
5

AFTER SORTING:
lg1
pw1
42
------------
   5
   6
   20200401
   3
   4
   20200501
   1
   2
   20200601
------------
3
lg2
pw2
43
------------
   50
   60
   20200401
   30
   40
   20200501
   90
   100
   20200501
   10
   20
   20200601
   70
   80
   20200801
------------
5
```